# Kubernetes reserving headroom on nodes to allow memory peaks

Tags: kubernetes, memory, kubernetes-pod, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I'm running a pod on k8s that has a baseline memory usage of about 1GB. Sometimes, depending on user behaviour, the pod can consume much more memory (10-12GB) for a few minutes, and then drop down to the baseline level.

What I would like to configure in k8s, is that the memory **request** would be quite low (1GB), but that the pod will run a node with a much higher memory capacity. This way when needed the pod will just grow and shrink back. The reason I don't configure the **request** to be higher, is that I have multiple replicas of this pod, and ideally I would want all of them to be hosted on 1-2 nodes, and let each one peak when needed, without spending too much.

It was counter intuitive to find out that the memory **limit** configuration does not affect node selection, meaning if I configure the limit to be 12GB I can still get a 4GB node.

Is there any way to configure my pods to share some large nodes, so they will be able to extend their memory usage without crashing?

Comment: Have you looked at [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)? You could have "xlarge" nodes with e.g. 16GB of memory and have these pods only schedule onto those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

### Resource Requests vs Limits

Memory limit doesn't affect node selection, but memory request does. This is because the concept of `resource request` and `resource limit` serve a different purpose.

1. Resource request makes sure that your pod has ***at least*** requested amount of resources at all times.
2. Resource limit makes sure that your pod ***does not have more than*** the limit amount of resources at any time. E-g not setting memory limits right leads to OOM (out-of-memory) kill on pods, and this happens very often.

Resource requests are the parameters used by the scheduler to determine how to schedule your pods on certain nodes. Limit are not used for this purpose and it is up to the application designer to set pod limits correctly.

### So What Can You Do

You can set your pod request the same way you are doing currently. Say, 1.5GiB of memory. You can then, from your experience, check that your pod can consume as much as 12GiB of memory. And you are running 2 pods of this application. Therefore, if you want to schedule both these pods on a single node and not have any issues, you have to make sure your node has:

```
total_memory = 2 * pod_limit + overhead (system) OR
total_memory ~= 2 * pod_limit
```

> Overhead is the memory overhead of your idle node which can account for usage by certain OS components and your cluster system components like `kubelet` and `kubeproxy` binaries. But this is generally a very small value.

This will allow you to select the right node for your pods.

### Summary

You will have to ensure for your pod to have a lot more memory in order to handle that spike (but not too much, so you will set a limit). You can read more about this [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/).

> Note: Strictly speaking, pods don't `shrink and grow` they have a fixed resource profile, which is determined by the `resource requests` and `resource limits` in the definition. Also note that, a pod is always "occupying" the requested amount of resources, even if it is not using them.

### Other Elements to Control Scheduling

Additionally, you can also use node-affinities to add a 'preference' for the scheduler to schedule your pods. I say a `preference` because node affinities are not definite rules, but guidelines. You can also use `anti-affinities` to make sure certain pods don't get scheduled on the same node. Just keep in mind, that if a pod is in danger of not being scheduled, the `affinity` or `anti-affinity` rules can be possibly ignored by the scheduler.

The last option is, you can use `nodeSelector` on your pod, to make sure it lands on the node which specifies the conditions of the selector. If no node matches this selector, your pod will be stuck in `Pending` state, meaning it cannot be scheduled anywhere. You can read about this [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/).

So, after you've decided which nodes you want your pod to be scheduled on, you can label them, and use a selector to ensure the pods are scheduled on the matching node.

It is also possible to provide a specified `nodeName` to your pod, to force it to schedule on a particular node. This is an option rarely used. Simply because nodes can be added/deleted in your cluster and this will require you to change your pod definition every time this happens. Using `nodeSelector` is better since you can specify general attributes like a `label` which you can attach to a new node you add to the cluster and the pod scheduling will not be affected, neither will be the pod definition.

Hope this helps.